# Getting null response - azure API calling c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

Here I try to hit the API which is hosted in azure. It have to give a response as a result value - "Registered Successfully".

But the response that I got when debugging the program is "null". And also I used to call this API in a try catch block. It doesn't enter into catch block but shows a null response.

But it return valid response when I run it in POSTMAN application.

Please anyone let me know what is the problem in my code.
[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp7WI.png) This is the postman screenshot
Here is my code

```
 HttpClient client = new client();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", ApiKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        string strAttn = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
        strAttn += "~" + personName;
        strAttn += "~" + val;
        string Uri = "https://orgdev.azure-api.net/APIDev/Attendance?guid=" + personID + "&timeofattendance=" + strAttn + "";       


        try
        {
            var lntResponse = await client.GetAsync(Uri);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exc = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Coulld you provide screenshot of your Postman request?

Comment: It seems you need to use [UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2) to escape invalid chars in your URL.

Comment: @AlexanderI. But the same link works in postman app

Comment: In postman you have a slash after /Attendance in url.

Comment: @majewka yes. I'm

Comment: And in code you don't have it. Did you try to update it?

Comment: It works in postman whether I put the slash symbol or not.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `string Uri = ...`, see if the URL matches your Postman. Also, why are you bypassing certificate validation?

Comment: @evilSnobu Yeah I've checked and I copied that URL and that is also worked in postman. And are you try to say the certificate verification is not required?

Comment: Go to http://requestbin.net/, create a bin, point your code to it and look at path and parameters.

Comment: @evilSnobu I've created a bin. What is the use of it?